# gv$aq versus queue_table

Tags: oracle, oracle-aq

I understand that `gv$aq` is a system wide view which contains number of messages in different states across ALL the queues in the database.

My question is: since `gv$aq` would be containing a lot more data compared to any given `queue_table`, querying this view to get the information (no. of messages, etc) for a particular `queue_table` would take a lot more time than directly querying the `queue_table` itself. Is there any specific reason why we should be better off querying `gv$aq` and not the queue table itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The view `qv$aq` contains only the statistics for each queue like number of messages or average wait time.  The `queue_table` contains all individual messages.

To get the number of messages from a `queue_table`, Oracle would have to inspect all messages and sum them up. To get the stats from the `qv$aq` view, Oracle simply looks them up from system memory, which is much faster.